# execute a lambda function in different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

Due to fixed requirements, I need to execute some code in a specific thread, and then return a result. The main-thread initiating that action should be blocked in the meantime.

```
void background_thread()
{
  while(1)
  {
    request.lock();
    g_lambda();
    response.unlock();
    request.unlock();
  }
}

void mainthread()
{
  ...
  g_lambda = []()...;
  request.unlock();
  response.lock();
  request.lock();
  ...
}
```

This should work. But it leaves us with a big problem: background thread needs to start   with response mutex locked, and main-thread needs to start with request mutex locked...

How can we accomplish that? I cant think of a good way. And isnt that an anti-pattern anyways?

Comment: This idea is faulty anyway. After the main thread executes `request.unlock()` the background thread may loop multiple times, execute the lambda multiple times and unlock the response mutex which is not locked.

Comment: It sounds as if you might be better off with two producer-consumer queues: one for the main thread producing the lambdas/task run by the secondary thread and one for the results produced by the secondary thread and read/processed by the main thread.  As presented, though, it does look like an xy-problem.

Comment: please show a [mre]. Is `std::thread t(g_lambda); t.join();` not sufficient (though rather pointless)?

Comment: user253751 is right. hmm.... @AlanBirtles no, it  has to be be a specific thread, not just any background thread.
That sucks. I will think more about it and look into  alternatives with the consumer queues...  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing tasks to background thread could be accomplished by a producer-consumer queue. Simple C++11 implementation, that does not depend on 3rd party libraries would have `std::condition_variable` which is waited by the background thread and notified by main thead, `std::queue` of tasks, and `std::mutex` to guard these.

Getting the result back to main thread can be done by `std::promise`/`std::future`. The simplest way is to make `std::packaged_task` as queue objects, so that main thread creates `packaged_task`, puts it to the queue, notifies `condition_variable` and waits on `packaged_task`'s future.

You would not actually need `std::queue` if you will create tasks by one at once, from one thread - just one `std::unique_ptr<std::packaged_task>>` would be enough. The queue adds flexibility to simultaneosly add many backround tasks.

Comment: Thanks! One question:
If i know i always block the main-thread, can i drop the std::packaged_task and just use std::function directly? 
Return value would be signaled back using the same condition_variable. 
Would there be any (performance) advantages over packaged_task + future?

Comment: You can. Although I'f prefer a different condition_variable. There might be performance advantage.